# sequence of random variables with density function

Tags: probability, weak-convergence, density-function

I have maybe a trivial question but I can't find an example. Is there a sequence of random variables $(X_{i})_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ with density function $p_{X_{i}}$ such that this sequence converge in Distribution to Zero?

Comment: Have you considered a sequence of random variables that are normally distributed with mean $0$ and variance $\{1/n\}$?

Comment: Thanks! Then I consider the characteristic function of this sequence

Comment: A simple example is $\{\frac X n\}$ where $X$ has normal distribution (or any distribution with a density).